# Can the bash prompt ring a bell only when the status code is non 0?

Tags: bash, status

I'm just wondering if it is possible for bash to ring the bell when displaying the prompt if the exit status code is not 0.

Basically, I want to hear the bell if any command I enter does not complete properly.

Comment: This is something you'll disable soon after you enabled it. Therefore, don't waste your time with it

Comment: Moreover, it's a better question for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), being more about customizing one's interactive environment than *writing software*.

Comment: ...that said, for somewhere you can hook a function that changes your PS1 (if that's how you want to go about this), see the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` has a special escape for adding a bell to the prompt: `\a`.
This is most useful if you use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to build your prompt dynamically. For example:

```
prompt () {
  last_es=$?
  PS1='\u@\h'
  if [ "$last_es" -ne 0 ]; then
    PS1+='\a'
  fi
  PS1+='\w \$'
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt
```

It doesn't matter too much *where* in the prompt you add the bell, as it won't affect the appearance of the prompt, and you are likely not going to notice precisely when the bell rings relative to the appearance of each character of the prompt :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# suggested by chepner for maximum portability
PS1='$( [ $? -eq 0 ]   ||  printf "\007" )$ '
```

Or this, MacOS:

```
PS1='$( [ $? -eq 0 ]   ||  echo ^G )$ '
```

You'll need to type `Ctrl-V Ctrl-G` to enter the `^G` properly (again, MacOS Terminal - YMMV ).

Comment: Or you should also be able to do: `echo -e '\a'` (not tested on macOS though, and `-e` is not a POSIX flag of `echo` at first sight)

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a "^G" output instead of a bell.  ...and yes, I used CTRL-V CTRL-G. I did not type ^ then G.  :)

Comment: As ErikMD suggests, try the non-POSIX echo feature:  `echo -e  "\a"`

Comment: Don't bother with `echo`; use `printf '\007'` or (for maximum portability) `tput bel`.

Comment: `tput bel` is the maximally portable one. Not every terminal might "display" ASCII 007 by ringing the bell. `tput bel` will output the terminal-specific sequence that *does* specifically tell the terminal to do so (though more often than not it *will* simply be ASCII 007).

Comment: Does MacOS not have the `printf` command? Incidentally, `printf '\a'` is clearer than `printf '\007'`.

Comment: @chepner: How portable is the assumption that the `tput` command is available?

Comment: @KeithThompson It's part of the POSIX specification, though in this case I mean portable in the sense that you aren't assuming anything about the terminal being used: those details are encapsulated in your `terminfo` database.

Comment: I forgot that `\a` was available to `printf` as a synonym for `\007`.